Unix: Open file in $EDITOR at x,y position
I'm trying to create a CLI tool that works with grep and opens files at a specified positions.
I'm wondering if there is a standardized way to open a file at a specified line+column that works across different unix editors (vi, vim, nano etc.).

This got marked as a duplicate, but it only shows how you open in vim. I want to build a CLI tool that can handle most common editors.... not just vim.
